# How to create one Button that clicks all mentioned buttons one by one

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have multiple buttons in my form that perform certain SQL Server functions. I want to make a Universal Button too that clicks all buttons one after another. It is mandatory for them to execute one after another in specific order. So one button cannot execute until the previous in order isn't completed executing. 
How do i achieve this? 
I can use `'button.PerformClick()'` but it will not wait for the previous button actions to complete. 
Kindly help

Comment: "*one button cannot execute until the previous in order **isn't** completed*" -> do you mean "**is**"?

Comment: Suppose Button1 takes some time to complete execution, only after it has completed execution i want Button2 to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating boolean for each button and set it to `true` after it has completed its orders? Then you could reset them all to `false` when all of them were executed.
You'd have to do something like `if(booleanIsTrue) button.PerformClick();` while looping around the buttons.

Example:

```
//in the form
Bool btnsAllCompleted = false; //to check if they have all completed
Bool btn1Completed = false; //for all your buttons

//this inside the universal button
while(!btnsAllCompleted)
{
    button1.PerformClick(); //first one without any check
    if(btn1Completed) button2.PerformClick(); //inside the perform click you'll have to set its boolean to true at the end
    if(btn2Completed) button3.PerformClick();
    //.
    //.
    //.
    if(btnXCompleted /*last button*/) btnsAllCompleted = !btnsAllCompleted
}
setAllBtnsCompletedToFalse(); //a function to set them all to false again
```

Comment: Yes i thought the same but I am not good with scope. So where do I declare this, form_load? And how do i access them inside  the button code?

Comment: Well you could declare them in the form and access them from inside the button without any problem.
How many buttons have to be triggered? If they're many you should create a list of buttons and loop through it with a `foreach`

Comment: Can you post an example that will be of great help. I know it is a lot to ask. It is okay if you cannot and thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: There, I added a quick example (not optimal but it will do the job). 
It's no problem, if it helped mark it as an answer!

Comment: The event handlers are going to run asynchronously using PerformClick (as in it's going to return immediately, and your completed bools will still be false). You will want to call the actual method that handles the click.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Task`, and `TaskCompletionSource`. Something like (the "cheating" method, requires no changes to existing click event handlers other than adding a `SetResult`):

```
tcsResponse1 = new TaskCompletionSource<Button1ResponseObject>();
Button1.PerformClick();
responseStatus = tcsResponse1.Task.Wait();

tcsResponse2 = new TaskCompletionSource<Button2ResponseObject>();
Button2.PerformClick();
responseStatus = tcsResponse2.Task.Wait();

...
```

In the perform button action methods, you'll do something like:

```
tcsResponse1.SetResult(new Button1ResponseObject {/* init here */};
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite the code that does the DB action as:

```
private async Task<MyReturnType> Button1Action()
{
    ...
    return new MyReturnType{ /* init as necessary */}
}
```

Then call it as:

```
var button1Result = await Button1Action();
var button2Result = await Button2Action();
// etc.
```

You would also need to modify your `Click` event handlers to `await` the method that does the actual work.

You will want to review [Variable Scope in Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and make sure you understand exactly what is going on (hint: if you don't and attempt to run the button click sequence more than once, you may end up with task completed exceptions).

From the very limited details provided, it sounds like you are performing some sort of workflow. It might be worth investigating Windows Workflow Foundation.

Comment: Sir I am very sure your solution works but I am not looking for such concrete solution. This may be the correct way but I don't have the time to learn and implement it. The other Answer is simple and will get the job done( even if it might not be the optimal way of doing it). I wish I could also select Your solution as the answer.

Comment: Goliadkin's answer will work as long as the functions you are calling are synchronous (i.e. the caller blocks until they return). If they're called asynchronously (e.g. by simulating a button click), or if they do anything asynchronously (e.g. provide a callback for a long-running db operation) you're going to run into trouble. Also, if you're launching off the UI thread, you really want to be doing things asynchronously (and probably disabling those other buttons while you're at it).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Occam's razor

```
public void ClickAll(object sender, smthIForgot e)
{
   ClickButton1(null, null);
   ClickButton3(null, null);
   ClickButton2(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Will this execute Button3 only after Button2 has completed execution?

Comment: It depends on your code in Button2. By default - yes.